# Android - "onConfigurationChanged()" not called when switching to same orientation (i.e landscape to reverse landscape))

Tags: android

I have this in my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.apps.foo.bar" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainPreviewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now the problem is here:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
         .............
         .................
          ............
    }
```

This is being called fine when I rotate the screen from portrait to landscape.
But once I am in landscape, if I turn to the other landscape (i.e 180 degrees)
it is not firing. The strange thing is that it fires only from `portrait` to `landscape` and `landscape` to `portrait`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flipping from landscape to reverse landscape is not a configuration change as it is invisible to the environment the app is in and hence the system does not send an event.

You can find more information and alternate solutions here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/IgBNQNgFUmk

Comment: Ok, I had a look, it seems to much work for what I am doing. Could I restrict my app to rotate to 1 landscape and 1 portrait, mode only ?

Comment: From my knowledge, I don't think that is possible. The problem is you can disable the reverse orientation all together for a particular configuration (portrait/landscape) but not both.

Comment: This is weird... Why is google not seeing this as an issue, flipping from landscape to reverse landscape should be  a configuration change

Comment: I could rotate the screen programmatically right ? with one button

Comment: Yes. Call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) to go to landscape and setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) for portrait.

Comment: will that still trigger the `onConfigurationChanged`